# Apply coupon automatically for one shipping method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

On Woocommerce, I am trying to apply a coupon based on a specific shipping method.

There is two shipping method set:

1. Free Shipping (3 Days): £0.00
2. DPD Next Day: £4.00

If the customer selects DPD Next Day: £4.00 shipping method, a specific coupon code "discount4" should be applied automatically.

If the customer selects Free Shipping (3 Days): £0.00 shipping method, the coupon code shouldn't be applied.

Any help or track is appreciated.

Comment: To the community: Kindly consider that this thread is not too broad even if the OP hasn't provided any code in his question. If you look at my answer code, it is just a very little code snippet that took me few minutes to make. So please reopen the thread as it's useful to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will auto apply a coupon, if the chosen Shipping Method is not "Free shipping" and will remove that coupon if it's applied and customer change to "Free shipping":

```
// Add / remove coupon based on cosen shipping
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_removing_coupon_shipping_based' );
function adding_removing_coupon_shipping_based( $cart ) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // HERE the specific coupon code
    $coupon_code = 'discount4';

    $coupon_code     = wc_format_coupon_code( $coupon_code );
    $chosen_shipping = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0];
    $applied_coupons = $cart->get_applied_coupons();

    $is_free = strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'free_shipping' ) !== false;
    $is_applied = in_array( $coupon_code, $applied_coupons );


    if ( $is_applied && $is_free )
        $cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    elseif ( ! $is_applied && ! $is_free )
        $cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If you have multiple shipping methods, you should give in your question the correct shipping method rate ID like "`flat_rate:18`" for **DPD Next Day: £4.00**, to be targeted in the code instead of free shipping which always start by `free_shipping`…

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your code let me check if its working or not